# Where can I find the Dockerfile from an image on Google Container Registry?

Tags: dockerfile, google-container-registry

I can pull the image `gcr.io/tfx-oss-public/tfx-workshop:latest` from Google Container Registry, but I would like to see the Dockerfile for how this image was created so that I can adapt an existing Dockerfile similary. Where can I find the Dockerfile for this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Dockerfile for the specific image that I was looking for at:

https://github.com/tensorflow/workshops/blob/master/tfx_airflow/buildfiles/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Not all the images at Google Container Registry are open source and/or provide publicly available Dockerfile.

As possible workaround, you can pull a container image and show the "history" for the container. This shows you how it is built and what the original starting image. This does not mean that you access the original image. You can add to and remove parts of the image. You can also export an image to a tar archive file, modify and then reimport.

**EDIT** Some images could be available at GitHub and provide publicly available Dockerfile. You can check and if you fond nothing follow instructions above.